# How to move ".csv.gz" files in aws S3 to another folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have list of files and folders in an S3 bucket

```
aws s3 ls s3://myBucket/

                       PRE 20/
                       PRE 21/
                       PRE 22/
                       PRE activity/
                       PRE county/
                       PRE nyboundaries/
                       PRE prova/
                       PRE result20200319_part0/
                       PRE result20200319_part0_Prova/
                       PRE result20200319_part1/
                       PRE result20200319_part1_Prova/
                       PRE test/
                       PRE test0/
2020-03-25 15:13:43  258487829 data000000000000.csv.gz
2020-03-25 23:52:08  258547969 data000000000001.csv.gz
2020-03-25 15:13:44  258444475 data000000000002.csv.gz
2020-03-25 23:52:06  258548668 data000000000003.csv.gz
2020-03-25 23:52:25  258482769 data000000000004.csv.gz
2020-03-25 15:13:44  258537299 data000000000005.csv.gz
2020-03-25 15:13:44  258658050 data000000000006.csv.gz
2020-03-25 15:13:44  258630461 data000000000007.csv.gz
2020-03-25 23:51:30  258556337 data000000000008.csv.gz
```

I would like to move all the files with the extension `.csv.gz` to a new folder that I would like to call `19`. I tried this but it dos not work

```
aws s3 mv s3://myBucket/ s3://myBucket/19 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv.gz"
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: That it does not move the files

Comment: Works fine for me, what's does `aws --version` return?

Comment: how can I check the version from the command line?

Comment: `aws --version`

Comment: `aws-cli/1.17.10 Python/3.8.1 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.14.10`

Comment: I copied a single file in the folder and it worked. It created the folder and the file is in there